# Errors when installing updates

Tags: 12.04, updates

I am getting the following errors when installing updates. They started to appear after I upgraded my system to 12.04.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-common
 samba-common-bin
 samba
 grub-pc
 grub-gfxpayload-lists
 Setting up samba-common (2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2) ...
 perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 dpkg: error processing samba-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin depends on samba-common (>= 2:3.4.0~pre1-2); however:
 Package samba-common is not configured yet.
 dpkg: error processing samba-common-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-common (= 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.2); however:
 Package samba-common is not configured yet.
 samba depends on samba-common-bin; however:
 Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.
 dpkg: error processing samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.6) ...
 Setting up grub-pc (1.99-21ubuntu3.1) ...
 perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are problems with the `samba` package.

Type `sudo apt-get --purge remove samba` in the terminal to remove the package.  This removes the Samba server that you installed.